# Can't access a folder in java package

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I want to read all of the files from within my package without using my entire file path. For example I can use something like this to get all of the files in a dir.

```
new File("/Users/me/Documents/workspace/testing/src/main/java/resources/").listFiles()
```

When I have a package in intellij that looks like this:

```
main
- java
--com.testFile
--resources
```

I read this: [Read file from a folder inside the project directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16745018/read-file-from-a-folder-inside-the-project-directory). However I want to be able to do this without specifying the the whole path.

For example it is explained here:
[How to read a file (e.g txt file) from another java package withouth specifying the absolute path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887138/how-to-read-a-file-e-g-txt-file-from-another-java-package-withouth-specifying)

I thought I could do something like

"src/main/java/resources" but every combination I try fails when plugged in to:

```
new File("/Users/me/Documents/workspace/testing/src/main/java/resources/").listFiles()
```

I could have sworn I've done this before like this? Am I making a silly mistake?

As of right now it can't locate the file. It's being run from a file in a file in java -> com.thisproject/app

For example I'm seeing:

```
File folder = new File("src/");
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
```

have listOfFiles be null.

Comment: File can only get paths from the filesystem. What you want is to get a _resource_  from your project. Like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16570523/getresourceasstream-returns-null

Comment: On UNIX system paths that start with `/` are absolute paths, if you want to use a relative path, don't include the `/` at the start.

Comment: @Titus I tried "src/main/java/resources" it fails as well

Comment: @Sekkuar can you explain how I might use resource to get a list off all the files? Can I do it in the same way as I was above?

Comment: I'm not sure... but I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676097/java-resource-as-file

Comment: @Sekkuar I actuallly got it to work. (answer below) but i'm still not sure why it works while src doesnt.

Comment: *"I want to read all of the files from within my package without using my entire file path."*  Application resources will become embedded resources (in a Jar) by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Sorry, could you explain that? As in I should access via what would be compiled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved...
This was actually kind of weird. Everything I found online said to reference src/main etc... Which is my file path.

However I was able to access it through:

```
new file("java/resources").listFiles();
```

Which works perfectly. If I were to try any of the below combinations:

```
new file("/java/resources").listFiles(); 
new file("main/java/resources").listFiles(); 
new file("src/main/java/resources").listFiles();
```

They all fail.

For system info I'm using intellij, Mac OS, I'm working on a intellij created webapp. Not sure if that makes a difference.

If anyone knows why src/... doesn't work I'd love to know.

Comment: Well, you are using an IDE right? Your compiled code probably is moved and executed in a different folder than the src/main

Comment: mmm interesting. Thank you. I didn't realize that it would be compiled elsewhere. I must read up on that

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me with eclipse running on Windows OS:

```
System.out.println(new File("src/").listFiles().length); // printing the no. of files for checking.
```

So, for you it would be: `"src/main/java/resources/"`.

Comment: I'm seeing 
        File folder = new File("src/");
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
where listOfFiles is null